# A function that explicit a product in Maple?

Tags: maple

I want for the product (a+b)(a-b) to have a^2-b^2. Which function should I write before the product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you want is `expand`.

```
 expand( (a+b) * (a-b) );
```